# Como posso usar ponteiro como vetor?

Tags: c

o codigo ainda não está completo, no entando, desde já, já não consigo botar parar rodar

alguém consegue me dar um norte, se trata de ponteiros em Linguagem C

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*
     Defina uma estrutura que irá representar bandas de música.
    Essa estrutura deve ter :
    nome da banda
    tipo de música 
    número de integrante
    posição do ranking essa banda está dentre as suas 5 bandas favoritas.


*/

typedef struct {
    char bandaNome[15];
    char bandaTipo[15];
    int bandaQtd, 
        bandaRank;
}Bandas;

int contador=0;

int estruturaBanda(Bandas *banda[3])
{
    
    for(contador = 0 ; contador < 3 ; contador++)
    {
        printf("Digite o nome da banda : ");
        gets(banda[contador]->bandaNome);
        fflush(stdin);
        
        printf("Digite o tipo de banda : ");
        gets(banda[contador]->bandaTipo);
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    
    
}

int main (void)
{
    
    Bandas grupo;
    estruturaBanda(&grupo); 
        
    
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: De início considere que sua estrutura `Bandas` só tem uma banda. Está consrtruindo errado. é muito mais simples se tiver as duas: `Banda` e `Bandas` e assim não vai precisar desses contadores toda hora...

Answer (score 1):

### Um *Norte*

```
typedef struct {
    char bandaNome[15];
    char bandaTipo[15];
    int bandaQtd, 
        bandaRank;
}Bandas;
```

Isso descreve uma e uma só banda. Porque `Bandas` no plural? e se tudo aí dentro se refere a uma banda não há razão para repetir toda hora `banda`

```
int contador = 0;
```

Nao use um contador separado. Só dá trabalho. Use outra estrutura. Se chama encapsulamento e é muito conveniente.

Compare:

```
typedef struct
{
    char     nome[15];
    char     tipo[15];
    unsigned qtd;
    unsigned rank;

} Banda;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned qtd;
    unsigned lim;
    Banda    B[5];

} Bandas;
```

Assim cada coleção de bandas tem um contador DENTRO e pode passar o endereço do conjunto como parâmetro

#### nunca escreva um programa interativo

Isso só gasta seu tempo. Se precisa ser interativo coloque isso depois que estiver funcionando. O que importa é começar a testar logo e implementar as funções de que precisa. Use constantes, geradores e arquivos. É trivial ler arquivos em C e é muito mais simples que ficar parado inventando nomes e valores toda vez que vai testar o programa

#### todos esses exercícios para iniciantes tratam algum tipo de container

é a lista de ingressos, de livros, de carros, de músicas, de bandas. Escreva antes de tudo uma função que mostra a coleção. E nunca escreva coisas como

```
int estruturaBanda(Bandas* banda[3])
```

porque

- é muito limitante porque é interativa
- inclui um vetor e um índice.

Exemplo de uma função simples:

```
int mostra(Bandas*, const char*);
```

Assim você passa só o endereço do container e um título. E fica livre para mudar o que precisar lá denro da função ou na chamada...

#### um programa de exemplo

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    char     nome[15];
    char     tipo[15];
    unsigned qtd;
    unsigned rank;

} Banda;

typedef struct
{
    unsigned qtd;
    unsigned lim;
    Banda    B[5];

} Bandas;

int mostra(Bandas*, const char*);

int main(void)
{
    Banda ex_banda = {"The Ones", "Metal", 5, 5};

    Bandas todas = {.qtd = 0, .lim = 5};

    todas.B[2] = ex_banda;
    todas.B[1] = (Banda){"The Others", "Rock", 8, 3};
    todas.B[0] = ex_banda;
    todas.qtd  = 3;
    mostra(&todas, "\tT e s t e\n");
    return 0;
}

int mostra(Bandas* col, const char* tit)
{
    if (col == NULL) return -1;
    if (tit != NULL) printf("%s\n", tit);
    printf(
        "\t%d [de %d] Bandas nesse grupo:\n\n", col->qtd,
        col->lim);
    if (col->qtd == 0) return 0;  // colecao vazia
    printf(
        "             Banda           Genero   #Elem   "
        "Rank \n");
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < col->qtd; i += 1)
        printf(
            "   %15s  %15s  %5d  %5d\n", col->B[i].nome,
            col->B[i].tipo, col->B[i].qtd, col->B[i].rank);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
};
```

que mostra

```
        T e s t e

        3 [de 5] Bandas nesse grupo:

             Banda           Genero   #Elem   Rank
          The Ones            Metal      5      5
        The Others             Rock      8      3
          The Ones            Metal      5      5
```

Se escrever assim, em torno dos dados, antes de começar a escrever o programa de fato já pode começar a testar.

#### criando uma banda

```
    Banda ex_banda = {"The Ones", "Metal", 5, 5};
```

Bem mais simples que ficar digitando

#### criando uma coleção de bandas

```
    Bandas todas = {.qtd = 0, .lim = 5};
    todas.B[2] = ex_banda;
    todas.B[1] = (Banda){"The Others", "Rock", 8, 3};
    todas.B[0] = ex_banda;
    todas.qtd  = 3;
```

#### dando uma conferida

```
    mostra(&todas, "\tT e s t e\n");
```